# What is the most straightforward way to reformat all dates on my website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime, formatting

I'm building a WordPress based site and the plugin that delivers the core-functionality doesn't allow changing the date format via the translation files.

All dates are giving out in an American format ("03-24-2017") and I would like to display them in a European format instead ("24.03.2017").

What would be the most straightforward and efficient way to do this? I googled the problem and found several JS-based libraries, but many of them seem to be to expansive (i.e. they also transform things like temperature, etc.). What I'm looking for is a straightforward solution that just formats the date and doesn't come with too much other technical hangover.

Comment: are they hard coded that way? you'll need to show some context for what you are trying to change - in my *opinion*, it's far nicer to display dates in a format based on the end users locale, rather than forcing a format down people's throats :p Merkins usually can't handle anything un-a-merkin

Comment: The dates are given out with PHP in that format, so technically they're not hardcoded but the format is forced. It forces the format even though my WordPress settings are set to another date format. The plugin developer recommended I change it JS/jQuery-based and I think that is easier than modifying the plugin (updates etc.). I don't mind doing it location based, but as the site is German the other formats aren't really needed, so either solution is fine with me.

Answer (score 0):

The straight forward way id, Go to `Admin Panel`, Open `Settings`, you can check `Time Format`

Choose Custom and add `m.d.Y` format.

Comment: Thank you, but that doesn't work because the plugin developer has the date given out in a different format. I already set the `Time Format` to `m.d.Y` and it doesn't have any effect.